# Unable to reach localhost for XAMMP sid

Tags: sql, apache, xampp

I installed the xampp app on my pc in order to practice SQL.
After the full installation, I typed in chrome browser `http://localhost/SID/sid.php`

And I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'SQLite3' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\SID\sid.php:97 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\SID\sid.php(60): _init() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\SID\sid.php on line 97

Did anybody come across this?

Answer (score 0):

In your php config, find this line:

> ;extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll

remove semicolon and restart your XAMMP

Answer (score 0):

I think I know the SQL practice files you're talking about...

in the crud.php comment out:

```
$CRUD['DBVERSION'] = SQLite3::version();
$CRUD['DBVERSION'] = 'SQLite version ' . $CRUD['DBVERSION']['versionString'];
```

in the sid.php comment out:

```
 $SID['DBVERSION'] = SQLite3::version();
 $SID['DBVERSION'] = 'SQLite version '.$SID['DBVERSION']['versionString'];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your php.ini file, find this line:

;extension=sqlite3

remove semicolon and restart apache server in xampp.